# Enabling Cloudflare Proxy on Ghost.io hosted blog

Tags: cloudflare, ghost-blog

I've got a Ghost blog hosted on Ghost.io. In the setup process they help provision a CloudFlare DNS record and SSL certificate to serve the site.

In the setup their configuration seems to only use the Cloudflare DNS features, so Web Workers, Page Rules and other features of Cloudflare are not working on my main domain.

[image: No proxy enabled on cloudflare]

I think I could setup the following:

- `ghost.mydomain.net` -> `ghost.io` (No Proxy)
- `mydomain.net` -> `ghost.mydomain.net` (Proxy and Rewrite)

But I'd much rather do this in one go.

I tried forcing the proxy through the commandline and while the command succeeds, the value proxy features remain turned off in my Cloudflare dashboard:

[image]

Any cloudflare experts who could guide me towards the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Ghost and Cloudflare gave a bit of feedback. Due to the fact that Ghost has taken cloudflare control over my domain, only they can control the settings. This is currently a limitation of cloudflare and in the future select settings may come under control of the domain owner.

Ghost is currently using a fixed setup for all domains which a pretty good, but not the most secure out there. They don't offer options for Ghost Pro users change the settings at the moment as this may cause them to break things. I suppose broken blogs cause a lot of support overhead.

Using a setup like:

- `{guid}.jessehouwing.net` -> `scrumbug.ghost.io`
- `jessehouwing.net` -> `{guid}.jessehouwing.net`

will allow you to enable Cloudflare proxy on the desired domain, but any features will only available when people come in over the right url. Any specific security settings will not be available when people navigate to the `{guid}.jessehouwing.net` domain directly.

I suppose, until Cloudflare can split control and payment of domains controlled by 3rd parties, I'll have to live without Cloudflare workers.